# How to check existence of data in database using Yii2?

Tags: php, web, yii, yii2

I'm learning Yii2 and I'm trying to make a registration in my Yii basic project. The problem is that I can't check existence of some data from user input (in my case email and url) in my DB to make a unique email for every user.

```
public function actionRegistration()
{
    $model = new RegistrationForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
    {           
        if (Users::findOne($model->email) !== null)//Doesn't work
            $error_email = "That email is taken. Try another.";
        if (Users::findOne($model->url) !== null)//Doesn't work
            $error_url = "That url is taken. Try another.";

        if (!(isset($error_email) || isset($error_url)))
        {
            $db = new Users();
            $db->name = $model->name;
            $db->email = $model->email;
            $db->password = $model->password;
            $db->url = $model->url;
            $db->save();
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render('registration',
                    [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'error_email' => $error_email,
                        'error_url' => $error_url,
                    ]
                );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render('registration',
                [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is set validation rules in model.

Model :

```
class RegistrationForm extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord  {

...

public function rules(){
    return [
        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\Users', 'message' => 'This address is use.'],
    ];
}
```

And Controller

```
public function actionRegistration() {
$model = new RegistrationForm();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {           

        $db = new Users();
        $db->name = $model->name;
        $db->email = $model->email;
        $db->password = $model->password;
        $db->url = $model->url;
        $db->save();
} else {

    return $this->render('registration',
            [
                'model' => $model,
            ]
        );
}
```

}

Magic is in $model->validate()

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html

Your example cause a loops request and response with all data. $model->validate check by ajax and prevent send request php data.

Comment: Cool! Can you explain how to make the same with ajax validation, please?

Comment: And how to make a 'unique' validator for url field?

Comment: With ajax code is the same. Only need to adjust view to ajax comunications.

Answer (score 3):

`findOne()` is based on primary key  (tipically the id) for your needs  you should use

```
Users::findOne(['email' => $model->email]);
```

or better

```
Users::find()->where(['email' => $model->email])->one();
```

`one()` returns the model

you can also use exists()

```
Users::find()->where(['email' => $model->email])->exists();
```

that returns boolean

Comment: @yutsura   ok  .. the comment was  not for you but for who downvote and don't leave a motivation .. .. is not fair "throw the stone and hide the hand"

Answer (score 2):

```
Users::find()->where(['email' => $model->email])->exists();
```